# How to check data in Array by using eloquent method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am working on a quiz. Below is a method and I am trying to get an array that can work in `in_array` function:

```
public function mcq($id)
  {
    $questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->first();
    $question_check = TestsResultsAnswer::where('user_id', auth::id())->pluck('question_id')->toArray();
    $sponsors = Sponsor::All();
    return view('pages.mcq', compact('questions', 'sponsors', 'question_check'));
  }
```

Below is blade code where I am passing the `question_check` variable by using `in_array` function:

```
                  @foreach ($questions as $key => $question)
                    @if(in_array($key, $question_check))
                    {{'Question Already Attempted'}}
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
```

But I am getting following error:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lea\resources\views\pages\mcq.blade.php)
```

My goal is to check if question was already attempted then print something. Please Help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `first()` will return a Model and not a collection, so you can't loop through. Use `get()` to fetch the result as a collection.

I.e: Instead of this

```
$questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->first();
```

do this

```
$questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->inRandomOrder()->limit(1)->get();
```

This should fix your current problem.

Considering this,

> My Target is to make a check if question already attempted then print something.

I think this is what you really want to do.

In Controller

```
$questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->inRandomOrder()->get()
```

In Blade

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
  @if(in_array($question->id, $question_check))
    {{'Question Already Attempted'}}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks to help me :)